# Where should I place a custom project template so that VIsual Studio 2017 picks it up

Tags: windows, visual-studio, templates, project

How do I load a custom project template in Visual Studio 2017. I'm using the Community edition on Windows 10 x64

I tried placing the custom project template in

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033
2. C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

However it did not help.

Where should I place the template so that VS 2017 picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful:

[Creating Project and Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)

Comment: That info is for VS 2015. A line reads for latest documentation on VS 2017 RC see ... that link also does not have any information regarding project templats